# Identificar tipo de triangulo segun sus lado TKINTER

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy tratando de realizar una aplicación grafica con tkinter, en la cual realizo una funcion para poder resolver que tipo de triangulo es de acuerdo a los datos que se ingresan en **valor1, valor2, valor3**  pero no se en que estoy fallando, dejo lo que llevo avanzado hasta el momento para ver si alguien puede ayudarme a resolverlo.

```
 import tkinter
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("500x250")
ventana.title("Tipos de triangulos")

v1 = tkinter.Label(ventana, text = "valor1")
v1.pack()
valor1 = tkinter.Entry(ventana)
valor1.pack()

v2 = tkinter.Label(ventana, text = "valor2")
v2.pack()
valor2 = tkinter.Entry(ventana)
valor2.pack()

v3 = tkinter.Label(ventana, text = "valor3")
v3.pack()
valor3 = tkinter.Entry(ventana)
valor3.pack()

result = tkinter.Text(ventana, height = 5,  
              width = 25,  
              bg = "light cyan")
result.pack()


def main():
    l1 = int(valor1.get())
    l2 = int(valor2.get())
    l3 = int(valor3.get())
    if (l1 == l2 and l1 == l3):
        result.insert("equiletarero")
    else: 
        result.insert("escaleno")


btn1 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Calcular", command=main)
btn1.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Veo al menos 2 errores: (edición 3 errores, gracias al oportuno [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390156/identificar-tipo-de-triangulo-segun-sus-lado-tkinter/390221?noredirect=1#comment699075_390221) de @Jakala)

1. Tu clasificación de triángulos según sus lados está incompleta, ya que solo tomas 2 casos: [*equilátero*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tri%C3%A1ngulo_equil%C3%A1tero) (y no *equiletarero*) y [*escaleno*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tri%C3%A1ngulo_escaleno). Te falta [*isósceles*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tri%C3%A1ngulo_is%C3%B3sceles).
2. En tu elemento de tipo [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm), usas lo siguiente: `result.insert("equiletarero")` provocando un error de tipo: `TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'`
3. No evalúas si los datos introducidos efectivamente corresponden a un triángulo.

**SOLUCIÓN**

**Edición**

Para determinar si los valores introducidos son realmente pertenecientes a un triángulo, debemos comprobar que se cumple la [desigualdad triangular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desigualdad_triangular), la cual establece que la suma de cualesquiera dos aristas siempre debe ser mayor que la tercera restante.

```
a + b > c, a + c > b, b + c > a
```

Entonces podemos agregar una condición para determinar que se cumple esta desigualdad.

```py
if(not((lado1 + lado2 > lado3) and (lado1 + lado3 > lado2) and (lado2 + lado3 > lado1))):
  result.delete("1.0", tk.END)
  result.insert(tk.INSERT, "No es un triángulo")
```

Luego corregiremos el asunto de los tipos de triángulos según sus lados. Como ya sabemos, los triángulos se clasifican en 3 tipos según sus lados: equilátero (todos sus lados son iguales), isósceles (1 lado diferente) y escaleno (todos sus lados diferentes).

Para determinar el tipo de triángulo, usaremos una estructura `if ... elif ... else`, que nos permitirá analizar 2 tipos de características y si no se cumple ninguna de las 2 entonces significa que es la tercera característica de las 3 posibles.

Por ejemplo:

```py
if (lado1 == lado2 and lado1 == lado3):
  # Caso equilátero
elif(lado1 != lado2 and lado1 != lado3 and lado2 != lado3):
  # Caso escaleno
else:
  # Case isósceles
```

Ahora, corrigiendo el error al usar el *widget* `Text`, podemos escribir el siguiente programa:

```py
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()

ventana.geometry("500x250")
ventana.title("Tipos de triángulos")

lblPrimerLado = tk.Label(ventana, text = "Primer lado")
lblPrimerLado.pack()
txtPrimerLado = tk.Entry(ventana)
txtPrimerLado.pack()

lblSegundoLado = tk.Label(ventana, text = "Segundo lado")
lblSegundoLado.pack()
txtSegundoLado = tk.Entry(ventana)
txtSegundoLado.pack()

lblTercerLado = tk.Label(ventana, text = "Tercer lado")
lblTercerLado.pack()
txtTercelLado = tk.Entry(ventana)
txtTercelLado.pack()

def main():
    lado1 = int(txtPrimerLado.get())
    lado2 = int(txtSegundoLado.get())
    lado3 = int(txtTercelLado.get())

    if (not((lado1 + lado2 > lado3) and (lado1 + lado3 > lado2) and (lado2 + lado3 > lado1))):
        result.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        result.insert(tk.INSERT, "No es un triángulo")
    elif (lado1 == lado2 and lado1 == lado3):
        result.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        result.insert(tk.INSERT, "Equilátero")
    elif(lado1 != lado2 and lado1 != lado3 and lado2 != lado3):
        result.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        result.insert(tk.INSERT, "Escaleno")
    else:
        result.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        result.insert(tk.INSERT, "Isósceles")

btnClasificar = tk.Button(ventana, text="Calcular", command=main)
btnClasificar.pack()

result = tk.Text(ventana, height = 3,  
              width = 25,  
              bg = "light cyan")
result.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

He cambiado el nombre de las variables y además he corregido el error en el uso del *widget* de tipo `Text`.

Como puedes observar, antes de insertar un valor en el *widget* utilizo el método `delete()` de la siguiente forma:

```
result.delete("1.0", tk.END)
```

Y para insertar el valor de la clasificación, utilizo el método `insert()` de la siguiente forma:

```
result.insert(tk.INSERT, "valor")
```

De esta forma tu programa se ejecutará sin dificultad.

Comment: Como detalle, falta comprobar el caso de que no tengas un triángulo. La suma de los lados dos a dos, debe ser estrictamente inferior al valor del otro lado. Sino, no existe el triángulo

Comment: Mucha razón tienes @Jakala, en cuanto pueda edito la respuesta con la explicación de esa peculiar propiedad.